# Is there a way to set the default bookmark location in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I often bookmark pages on Chrome, and I have a generic folder for any bookmarks I don't feel like putting in its proper place. Anyway, Chrome decided to put my bookmarks automatically **in my last used folder.** This is very annoying. Is there a way that I can set this to a folder that I want, with an extension/setting/file  modification (like the properties file)?

[image: Bookmark Setting]

Answer (score 1):

As of October 2014, I'm seeing Chrome put the bookmarks in the most recently used folder. There is no default folder, per se. If you don't like where it's putting it, click Edit and change it.

Comment: That's not my experience, with sync turned on. I found this thread:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/_0oMzvyaa44
that suggests it is in fact an issue with synching, but given how old the Google ProductForums thread is ...

Answer (score 1):

It's not a direct answer to the question in the title. But it can solve the problem the asker is facing.

There are [3 ways](https://www.wikihow.com/Add-a-Bookmark-on-Google-Chrome) to bookmark the current page where you want it.

One is to [click and drag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGXBC.gif).

Put the generics directory right under the greenlock button, then you can easily add bookmarks to it.